# How can I turn distinct R G B arrays back into an image?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, python-imageio

In Python:

I read in an image and I want to process each channel (RGB) separately, then put the modified channels  back together into an image and save it to disk. I have tried everything I can think of, but I get mangled images back no matter what.

BTW, I can't use Pillow for most of this because I want 16 bits to process.

I've tried innumerable variations of this:

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def load_pic():
    global picky, reds, greens, blues, shape
    filename = "FinalStacked.fit"
    print(f"loading {filename}")
    picky = imageio.v3.imread(filename, plugin = "FITS")
    shape = picky.shape
    print(f"Image loaded, size = {shape}")

    reds = picky[0]
    greens = picky[1]
    blues = picky[2]
    print("picture loaded")

def finish():

    out = np.dstack((reds, greens, blues))
    
    im = Image.fromarray(out, 'RGB')
    print(im.mode)
    imageio.v3.imwrite("done.png", im)

load_pic()
finish()
```

But nothing seems to work. I would expect the above to return a reasonable facsimile of the input image, but it doesn't.

Comment: and you're already using Pillow -> `from PIL import Image`

Comment: Yup. But I'm not using it to read the image.

Comment: Edited my answer to read image using the function you used

Comment: And mentioned the error in your code, essentially you were slicing your image wrong

Comment: what shape did your `picky` have?

Comment: (3, 1080, 1920)

Comment: then your code is right.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments you are not actually getting the RGB channels with your code. Something like the below code will work for you:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as mp 

# read image get RGB
picky = imageio.v3.imread(filename)

# create image
Image.fromarray(picky, 'RGB')
```

The error in your code is that you're taking the wrong channels

```
# UPDATETHIS
reds = picky[:,:,0,]
greens = picky[:,:,1]
blues = picky[:,:,2]

out = np.dstack((reds, greens, blues))
print(picky.shape, out.shape)
```

Print:

```
((534, 800, 3), (534, 800, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm making progress.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work. picky.shape = (3, 1080, 1920), so I was grabbing the right channels.

Comment: Hmmm, can you share a demo image then, bcoz I get shape as (height, width, 3)

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6ecmtyia51m0if1ldoa56/moon.jpg?rlkey=m7iiiicvycgzix96rzcklgn5q&dl=0) Here's a nice picture of the moon.

Comment: Did you share the right image? ```filename = r'moon.jpg'```

```picky = imageio.v3.imread(filename)```

```print(picky.shape)``` the shape I get is ```(2160, 3840, 3)```

Comment: Here's the original file I was using. You'll need to ba able to open a FITS file. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/n194j53n0zlktewevyrib/FinalStacked.fit?rlkey=h9rtk90rgmdukkbfa61zbm0m6&dl=0)